# How to import Illustrator swatch libraries into InDesign - Adobe Indesign Mac?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, color, swatches

I have a very reach swatch library in adobe-illustrator like food colors and.... But in adobe-indesign I don't have many colors. Why? Can I import them to indesign?

Comment: That is in the Help for InDesign -- logically, the first place to look: http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/swatches.html#import_swatches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the **Swatch Panel** menu in Illustrator choose `Save Swatch
   Library as ASE'
2. Save that to somewhere you can locate.
3. In InDeign's **Swatch Panel** menu choose `Load Swatches` and select
   the .ase file you just saved.

You must save as an ASE file for InDesign to read the swatches.

Note: *All* Adobe applications can read and open .ase swatch files. So the same procedure is used when moving swatches between any Adobe applications.

Also Note: This only refers to **color swatches** in AI (global/spot/CMK/RGB). This **does not** work for gradient and pattern swatches in Illustrator. Gradient and pattern swatch types are **not** transferable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @scott Some colors are imported to Indesign this way. but when saving the swatch in illustrator, it gives me a message saying: `Swatches containing gradient,pattern, or tints are not currently exchangeable and will not be visible when opening this swatch file in other applications` how can I import them to my indesign as well?

Comment: You Can't. Gradient and patterns are not transferable, as the message states. Only **color** is transferable. You can not get Illustrator gradients or patterns into InDesign as swatches. Things just don't work that way. Your question stated nothing about patterns, or gradients for that matter.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. So I should save my object as tiff in illustrator and then import it to indesign, right? @scott

Comment: InDesign allows you to "Place" native illustrator (.ai) files. There's no blanket reason to save an AI file as a tiff for InDesign.

Comment: That is a good idea @scott But I feel the quality of figures are better when using tiff rather than ai. Am I wrong?

Comment: I can't definitely say without seeing art. However, vector art almost always reproduces better than raster art. In addition, vector art is generally smaller in size (kb) than raster art. I *never* convert vector to raster unless there's some very specific reason such as an illustration which *must* be delivered in raster form.

Comment: Yes, but one thing that was so strange for me, I saved all images in Tiff format in illustrator and then import them to indesign. after I finished the layout and export the page in pdf, it looks like tht all the images are in vector type bx with 3000% zoom the quality of images arent decreased.(why?) but one thing that bothers me are the white areas around the images after saving with illustrator :( @scott

Comment: Thats true, Thanks anyway for answering some of my questions :) I've just started to use these tools recently to write my book. So I have a very small knowdelge in this area. @scott

Answer (score 1):

Here is another tip: Let's say that you have used layer effects and transparency for your objects and you want to capture those as color swatches and apply them as though they are flat colors: Save your illustrator file as a pdf. Open it in Acrobat Pro and Open Preflight under the Tools menu. Go to PDF Fix-ups and select "Flatten Transparency". Then click "Analyze and Fix". Save the pdf and when you reopen it in Illustrator, you will see that it has objects with colors without transparency or layer effects. You can add these to your swatches. This is useful if you need to send the swatches over to Indesign and want the correct colors.