# Importing Illustrator pattern swatches into InDesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, patterns, swatches

Does anyone know if we can import Illustrator pattern swatches into an InDesign library or swatch pattern library?

Answer (score 2):

No. Illustrator **pattern** (and gradient) swatches are **not** transferable to any other Adobe application.

In addition, InDesign has **no** ability to create or use ***pattern*** swatches.

You *can* transfer *standard color swatches* from AI to INDD. Just not *pattern* or gradient swatches. See here: [How to import Illustrator swatch libraries into InDesign - Adobe Indesign Mac?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45030/how-to-import-illustrator-swatch-libraries-into-indesign-adobe-indesign-mac)

Answer (score 0):

What about CC libraries ? You can totally share swatches between Ai and ID ;)

Comment: Can you with pattern swatches?

Comment: Even with Libraries, InDesign has zero support for *pattern* swatches.

Comment: You are right, I did miss the "pattern" topic. My bad.